# find duplicates in two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates

I have two arrays like this:

```
var x = ['1','2','6'];
var y = ['4', '5','6'];
```

How do I find duplicates in two arrays in pure JavaScript and I would like to avoid using a loop?

Output - `duplicates: 6`

Comment: Does it need to be pure JS or can you use Underscore.js or jQuery?

Comment: hi, pure ! @Jezzabeanz

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885557/simplest-code-for-array-intersection-in-javascript

Comment: Similar quesiton [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885557/simplest-code-for-array-intersection-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var x = ['1','2','6'];
var y = ['4', '5','6'];

var overlap = x.filter(function(v,i,a){
  return y.indexOf(v) > -1;
});

console.log(overlap); // ['6']
```

Does this work for your purpose?

[MDN docs for `filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var x = ['1','2','6'];
var y = ['4', '5','6'];
var duplicate = [];
for (var i=0; i<y.length; i++) {
    var index = x.indexOf(y[i]);
    if (index > -1) {
        duplicate.push(x[index]);
    }
}

Output: ["6"]
```

Comment: "I would like to avoid using a loop"

Comment: @DavidBarker okay. It's `O(array1.length * array2.length)` but for reasonably small arrays and on modern hardware this shouldn't remotely cause an issue